# Referencia a la misma instancia del ViewModel desde otro Composable - JetPack Compose

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, jetpack-compose

Cuál es la mejor práctica para obtener la misma instancia de un viewmodel desde otro composable que esta ubicado en otra pantalla. A continuación proporciono parte del código en el que estoy trabajando, estaré atento a sus aportaciones.

```
fun TodoList() {
    //Aqui esta la instancia
    val todoViewModel:TodoViewModel = viewModel()

    if (todoViewModel.state.value.isEmpty()) {
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Rounded.List, contentDescription = "", tint = Color.Gray)
            Text(
                text = "No hay ningun elemento en la lista aún",
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Light,
                color = Color.Gray
            )
        }
    }

    // Este es el otro composable que esta en una pantalla diferente
    fun NewTodoView(navController: NavController = rememberNavController()) {
    //Aqui quisiera obtener la referencia o la misma instancia ya creada
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta es mi propuesta de solución, también válida para pasar por parámetro más de un "viewmodel".

```
fun TodoList(
// pasar el view model como parámetro de la función
viewModel : TodoViewModel
) {
    
    if (viewModel.state.value.isEmpty()) {
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Rounded.List, contentDescription = "", tint = Color.Gray)
            Text(
                text = "No hay ningun elemento en la lista aún",
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Light,
                color = Color.Gray
            )
        }
    }

// Este es el otro composable que esta en una pantalla diferente
fun NewTodoView(
navController: NavController = rememberNavController(),
// Pasar el viewModel por parámetro
viewModel: TodoViewModel
) {
    // Aqui quisiera obtener la referencia o la misma instancia ya creada
    // viewModel.state.value
}
```

Un saludo,
Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).